# How can I find the limit $\lim_{x\to \frac12}\frac{4x^2 - 1}{\arcsin(1 - 2x)} $

Tags: limits, trigonometry

How can I find the limit

$$\lim_{\left(x\to 1/2\right)}\ \frac{4x^2 - 1}{\arcsin(1 - 2x)}\quad ? $$

Comment: Hello @Marcus McKenzie, welcome to MSE. Questions in the style "here is my problem, solve it for me" are usually not well received on this site. Please add in the question what attempts you have made yourself and what your exact problem is. That way, you will be more likely to get some help.

Comment: You should state the answer in  a proper way, see [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and show your work and effort on that. Follow the given hints and show your work here.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have

$$\frac{4x^2 - 1}{\arcsin(1 - 2x)}=\frac{(2x-1)(2x+1)}{1-2x}\frac{1-2x}{\arcsin(1 - 2x)}$$

then refer to the standard limit as $t\to 0\quad \frac{\arcsin t}{t}\to 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Obvious substitution

$\arcsin(1-2x)=y,2x=1-\sin y$

$y\to0,$ as $x\to1/2$